# Angular Observables and Http

Tags: angular, observable

I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around observables in Angular. I'm coming from the world of PHP, where things are definitely not async.

I have a component that simply displays a list of messages for a general topic. For now, I have one topic that all messages belong to. If the topic doesn't exist, then it should be created. The message and topic calls are all done through a REST api.

In a non-async world, I would program it in order. The message service would see if the topic exists. If it doesn't, then it has the topic service create it. After it has the topic, it then fetches all of the messages within that topic.

I understand that you subscribe to an observable, but what happens when there needs to be a series of things that need to happen in order? The [angular 2 http documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#) goes through a very simple example of updating the hero list when one call is made.

**Component**

```
export class NotificationListComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _notificationService:NotificationService) {
}

***

ngOnInit() {
    this.getNotifications();
}

getNotifications() {
      this._notificationService.getNotifications()
        .subscribe(
            notifications => this.notifications = notifications,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

**Notification Service**

```
...    
 getNotifications() {
     //  call the topic service here for general topic??

    return this.http.get('/messages?order[datesent]=DESC')
        .map((res) => {
            return res.json()["hydra:member"];
        })
        .map((notifications:Array<any>) => {
            let result:Array<Notification> = [];
            notifications.forEach((jsonNotification) => {
                var Notification:Notification = {
                    message: jsonNotification.message,
                    topic: jsonNotification.topic,
                    datesent: new Date(jsonNotification.datesent),
                };
                result.push(Notification);
            });
            return result;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
...
```

**Topic Service**

```
  ...
 getGeneralTopic() {
    var generalTopic;

    this.http.get('/topics?name=general')
        .map((res) => {
            return res.json()["hydra:member"][0];
        })
        .do(data => console.log(data))
        .subscribe(generalTopic => res);
}
...
```

Comment: When you say a "strict set of things" need to happen, do you mean - in order? or can it be out-of-order, and its more important to do something when all the things have completed?

Comment: I meant that a series of things need to happen in order. My wording was confusing

Comment: I started writing my answer before you posted the code and changed the title (:. Hopefully it'll be enough and you can update your code yourself...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How to reason about *Observables*?

Observables deal with *streams*. Streams can be pretty much anything, but you can think of them as ***abstract array of asynchronous events***. This is useful because you can now reason about them more clearly:

- ***abstract*** because Observable can produce a value of any type: `String, Boolean, Object`
- ***array*** because Observable has [`Operators`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) that work similar to JavaScript's array methods: `map(), filter(), reduce()`
- ***of*** because Observable is a wrapper for value(s)
- ***asynchronous*** because Observable *may* or *may not* execute
- ***events*** because Observable needs to be triggered

### When to use *Observables*?

You want to use Observables typically when you need to perform a task or an action that involves several steps. This can be your starting point, you can later simplify or increase complexity as needed.

You should have a "plan" or at least a vague idea what those steps should be. Sounds obvious, but many problems/issues occur because you don't know what you want (;

Once you have planned an action (as an array of steps) you can start from either end, but I think it's better to start from the end. At least until you learn more.

> I have a component that simply displays a list of messages for a general topic. For now, I have one topic that all messages belong to. If the topic doesn't exist, then it should be created. The message and topic calls are all done through a REST api.
>
> In a non-async world, I would program it in order. The message service would see if the topic exists. If it doesn't, then it has the topic service create it. After it has the topic, it then fetches all of the messages within that topic.

For your use case **The Plan** would be: `["(create topic)", "select topic", "show messages"]`. `messages` are ***abstract array***, `select` and `create` are ***asynchronous events***.

### How to use an *Observable*?

As I said above, let's start from the end - `"show messages"`.

```
<div *ngFor="#message of messages"></div>
```

We know we're dealing with `Observable.of(messages)` (this is how you would manually create it). Next, you need to 'fill' the *stream* of messages, and you can do it with `Http` service that returns `Observable`. Since messages you get from the server are wrapped in several "layers" by `Http` service, we can leverage ability of Observable to chain operators (operators return `Observable`) and get to the messages we need:

```
  getMessages(topic) {
    this.http.get("/messages?topic=" + topic)
      .map(response => response.json())
      // chain other operators here...
      .filter(message => !message.private)
  }
```

You can use whatever [Operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) you need here... which leads to the next big thing about Observables:

### “Hot” and “Cold” *Observables*

Observables are ***cold*** by default. This means that when you create an observable you just describe what it should do. It won't execute these actions immediately (like `Promises` do) it needs to be triggered.

You trigger it by subscribing to it, either manually with `subscribe()` method, or you can let Angular make it ***hot*** with `async` pipe (which does subscribing for you).

```
  getMessages(topic) {
    this.http.get("/messages?topic=" + topic)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(messages => this.messages = messages);
  }
```

### Watching for changes

Next thing to do (or previous since we're going backwards in **The Plan**) is to `"select topic"`. It would be nice to watch the value of selected topic and respond to it's change by loading new messages. This can be done with a [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).

> A Subject is a sort of bridge or proxy that is available in some implementations of ReactiveX that acts both as an observer and as an Observable. Because it is an observer, it can subscribe to one or more Observables, and because it is an Observable, it can pass through the items it observes by reemitting them, and it can also emit new items.

We can setup `topic$` to do this like so:

```
class ListComponent {
  public messages;
  public topic$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getMessages('posts');
    this.topic$
      .subscribe(topic => this.getMessages(topic));
  }

  getMessages(topic: string) {....}

  selectTopic(topic: string) {
    this.topic$.next(topic)
  }
}
```

### Wrap up

Last step is to `"(create topic)"` if one doesn't exist. Let's assume server would return an error if topic doesn't exist:

```
  getMessages(topic: string) {
    this.http.get(API_URL + topic)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
        messages => this.messages = messages, 
        error => this.createTopic(topic)
      );
  }

  createTopic(topic: string) {
    this.http.post(API_URL + topic, { body: JSON.stringify(topic) })
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Here's the [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8q3mQd?p=preview) with this example. As you can see it's not hard to do (50-ish lines of code...). You can easily move things around and create services where you need.

Comment: This answer is amazing. You really helped me to better understand observables. The idea of a [subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) is really neat, and without this post, I wouldn't have thought of looking in that direction. I really appreciate the help, and it allowed me to complete the task I needed.

Comment: Great answer, would it be fair to say that an Observable is similar to a C# Linq query?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, Reactive Programming allows to create asynchronous data streams. This means that you can leverage

The HTTP support of Angular2 leverages operators (flatMap, ...) to link streams together and implement complex processing chains. This means that you can use all concepts of Reactive Programming / RxJS to make an HTTP request part of an asynchronous data stream.

Here a simple sample that allows to execute a request based on the value of a form input (when updates occur):

```
this.inputControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).flatMap(
  val => {
    // Execute ab 
    return this.http.get(`http://...?filter=${val}`);
  }).subscribe((data) => {
    this.places = data;
  });
```

Operators can also allow to implement easily several issues in the context of HTTP:

- **Ensure to receive the latest when requests are executed in sequence** (for example based on user input). Sample of the `switchMap` operator that cancels the previous in-progress requests when a new one is triggered

  ```
  this.ctrl.valueChanges.switchMap(
    val => {
      return this.http.get(`http://...?filter=${val}`);
    });
  ```
- **Buffer events and trigger the last one after an amount of time**. Sample that waits for an inactivity of 500ms before executing the request based on the latest value of the input:

  ```
  this.ctrl.valueChanges.debounceTime(500).flatMap(
    val => {
      return this.http.get(`http://...?filter=${val}`);
    });
  ```
- **Retry when requests fail**. Sample of retry each 500ms and within 2s

  ```
  var params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('placename_startsWith', searchText);
  params.set('username', 'XXX');

  return this.http.get('http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON',
        { search: params })
    .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500))
    .timeout(2000, return new Error('delay exceeded'))
    .map(res => res.json().postalCodes);
  ```

Here are some articles regarding Reactive Programming that could help you:

- The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing by André Staltz - https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
- Everything is a stream by Rob Wormald - http://slides.com/robwormald/everything-is-a-stream

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure to understand your question, possibly `Observable.selectMany` and `Observable.and/thenDo/when` can help you.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/when.md

In your case, I think it makes you to create a transaction of fetching and inserting.