# Debugging HTTP request that is not being fired in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an Ionic 2 App. The app does all kind of HTTP requests without any problems.

Now I am adding a new HTTP request and it just won't fire and I have absolutely now idea why not.

```
sendPushToken() {
      console.log('test');
      return this.http.get(API_BASE_URL + '/token')
      .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

When I call the method the test gets logged to the console but the HTTP request does not happen. No error, nothing!

I tried diferente requests and tried to call it from diferente positions within my app...

The request just does not happen.

I have no idea where to start debugging nor how to ask this in a better way, as I know that this question is kind of broad.

All other http requests in the app continue to work without problems.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the request?

Comment: Have you subscribed to this request?

Comment: @AJT_82 oops, at the same time :)

Comment: @developer033 Yeah :D

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I think I will spend tonight working on my understanding of some fundamentals...

Comment: This can be useful, check the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470039/angular-2-observables-and-http

Answer (score 0):

To debug http requests in an east way, you can make use of chrome inspect function via an android device and over adb. To do this, use chrome and enter this url on your chrome (ionic run android has to be run first to have an debuggable app on your phone)

> chrome://inspect/#devices

and you will see something like this.

[image]

After that , you click on inspect and head over to network section, your http post will appear there if you have properly called the function.

Perhaps when you call the sendPushToken() function, try

```
this.sendPushToken();
```

Or

```
var zoneA = this;
zoneA.sendPushToken();
```