# Angular 2 - .http - Why do I need to .subscribe to a .map or .switchMap for console.log to work?

Tags: angular, dictionary, observable

I have a basic component that is trying to get data out of the `Params`. However I've noticed that my debug code will often not work if I am missing `.subscribe()`. If `.subscribe()` was commented out in this example, `Got Params??` wouldn't be printed to the console.

```
this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) =>{
    console.log("Got params??");
    console.log(params);
    // params['filename'])
    return 'cat';
  })
  .subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
  })
```

More code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


export class ParsedFileComponent implements OnInit {

  parsed: any;
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private route: ActivatedRoute 
  ) {      }
```

It seems as though the code within `.switchMap()` isn't being executed unless its subscribed to

Comment: That is by design, because if nothing cares about the result of the observable, then why run it at all? I can't seem to find the post saying that, but this article mentions it: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because **Observables** are **Cold** by default, they need to be triggered manually, in this case with the `subscribe()` method.

There's another type of **Observables** the **Hot** ones, they will be triggered by another thing, like the `async` pipe of angular, in this case you don't need the `subscribe()` method.

If you want a complete answer about this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470039/angular-2-observables-and-http), please upvote that answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Point what is wrong if you downvote an answer so we can learn.