# Angular Heroes tutorial heroes.component and dashboard.component

Tags: angular

I was following the angular heroes tutorial. The **heroes.component** is as shown below.

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[];

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(0, 5));
  }

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if(!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.addHero({ name } as Hero)
    .subscribe(hero => {
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
  }
}
```

The **dashboard.component** is as shown below.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

The **heroes.component.ts** add method has a subscribe callback to push the newly created hero into the heroes array so that the **heroes.component.html** can display the newly created hero. If I do not want to display the newly created hero in **heroes.component.html**, I will just remove the subscribe callback method.

However, when I remove the subscribe callback method in **heroes.component.ts**, the **dashboard.component.html** does not display my newly created hero.

Why does the **heroes.component.ts** need the subscribe method to reflect the change in **dashboard.component.ts**?

Are their heroes property related in some way?

Comment: Kindly spend some time and put some effort before posting a question. duplicate of [Angular Observables and Http](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35470039/5695162)

Answer (score 0):

When you subscribe to an observable it implies that it will not complete but will always keep updating the newly updated/deleted/added values.

Hence you can always be sure that the values which are displayed are not stale. Observables and promises differ in that sense, a **promise** will complete but an **observable** will keep updating the data until the component is not destroyed or an unsubscribe is not called on that observable.

Hope that helps.